# Ошибка в отдельном js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null?

Tags: javascript, html, css

я только начал изучать html и js и использовал скрипт для добавления класса к элементу. Если скрипт находится в html документе то всё работает, но если вынести скрипт в отдельный файл то происходит ошибка с classList

```
var height=0;
var width=0;
  if (self.screen) {     // for NN4 and IE4
       swidth = screen.width
       sheight = screen.height}
    else if (self.java) {   // for NN3 with enabled Java
      var jkit = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      var scrsize = jkit.getScreenSize();
      swidth = scrsize.width;
      sheight = scrsize.height;}
  if (swidth < 426) {
  document.querySelector('.mobile-menu').classList.add('mobile-menu-resize');
}
```

Подключаю через script в head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mobile-menu-resize.js"></script>
```

Comment: смею предположить что тег скрипт вы добавили в header, добавьте его в самый конец body, если мое утверждение верно, то на момент выполнения скрипта элементов еще нет

Comment: Скорее всего, элемент `.mobile-menu` не существует на момент выполнения скрипта. Помести код в обработчик события документа `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Благодарю, добавил строку <script type="text/javascript" src="/mobile-menu-resize.js"></script> в конец body и всё заработало, как сам не додумался, встретил где-то что лучше script в head писать, а про порядок загрузки забыл. Вариант с DOM возьму на заметку.

Comment: У способа с обработчиком есть один весьма приятный бонус: блок коллбэк-функции создает лексическое окружение - отпадает необходимость использовать IIFE. Ну и контекстом выполнения становится объект элемента, если функция не стрелочная.